# php glob function returns nothing

Tags: php

Hi Stackoverflow masters, 
I have problem with glob function php.

```
$gallery_full = glob("/var/www/home.com/uplo_1/*.*",GLOB_NOSORT);
print_r($gallery_full);
```

This lines returns me nothing. All dirs have chmod 777. In uplo_1 there are jpg and png files.
Any one know how to run it ?

Comment: try `uplo_1/*` instead of `uplo_1/*.*`

Comment: Ever saw a directory with a file/(dir) extension ?

Comment: see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/14084378/

Comment: @Fred-ii- still the same

Comment: Do have folder named ``home.com`` under ``www`` ??

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: try doing `print_r(__DIR__)` and include the result above, then we know what you're working with

Comment: @Rizier123 OP's syntax is correct. Might just be a path issue and/or something else. OP needs to check for errors and their system environment.

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments. i changed my method. its permission problem with other part of virtual machine

Comment: You're welcome @binar - Glad to see that the matter was resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** After testing your posted code with my own system path, there were no problems.

- Check to make sure you have your system path correct.
- Use [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) inside a file, look under **Environment**, then **DOCUMENT_ROOT**.

  - If you do not have access/privilege to use `phpinfo()`, then login to your admin panel, and/or contact your hosting provider for your system path, should that be the case.
- Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

> *"All dirs have chmod 777"*

- That isn't the safest setting. Use 755 for folders and 644 for files.

---

*Original answer before edit:*

This is what I use and would be better if your folder happens to contain files other than images.

- Sidenote: It's best for a folder to have an index file, otherwise someone may find the folder and have a peek at what's inside it, that's if you haven't taken care of this otherwise.

Ensure that the path is correct.

```
$imagesDir = '/path/to/files';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_NOSORT);
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

When I use `glob` I prepend the DOCUMENT_ROOT first, like this:

```
$fileCount = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/file.ext';
echo $fileCount;
```

This should work.